# Access a variable declared in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I wanted to access  a variable defined in  $.ajax({  outside the function . Inside ajax I have an if statement and else statement. If the control goes inside if, then after coming out from ajax function I need one function to run. So thinking of writing if outside ajax. Kindly let me know , if I can do like that?

```
success: function (msg) {
                if(msg.d == "No duplicate"){
             //code

                }
                else{
       //code
         }
```

After this, i write a confirm box which should be displayed only when it enters into if block.

```
 if (confirm("Are you sure you want to insert this new record ?") == false) {
                        hide();
                        return false;
                    }
```

Comment: Instead of describing your code, how about posting it?

Comment: Kindly let me know is this enough or I need to update the full code

Comment: @nishanth Why can't you just place the code inside the if-branch of the if-statement?

Comment: @sime-vidas because he'll be out of scope

Comment: @Sime Vidas: actually I can't because, that would be a problem for me when i insert the record(the next following steps)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it seems like you are trying to call a function, only if the ajax call succeeds, and some other condition (no duplicate) is met. It seems like it should be just as simple as calling this other function inside of your if statement:

```
function makeAjaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
        success: function(msg) {
            if (msg.d == "No duplicate") {
                doSomething();
            }
            else {
            }
        }
    });
}

function doSomething() {
    if (confirm(...)) {
    }
}
```

Comment: ya, I can but this is OnBeforeClientInsert method, so I can't just use some other function

Comment: @nishanth You should edit your question to indicate that you are using ASP.NET Grid, and are trying to perform some logic in the OnBeforeClientInsert method handler, which is defined elsewhere. This small fact completely changes the nature of your question!